# How to sort an array to bring out element that are the same?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
Array = [40, 2, 40, 10, 5, 6, 10, 5, 6, 18, 15]
```

Sort the array to bring out homogeneous element

Comment: Your array is invalid syntax.

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: The syntax is wrong I guess u know Wat I meant

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We are a community of volunteers passionate about programming and computer science. Nobody here offers a professional service to answer questions. If you want a question to be answered, you should take some effort to ask your question. You should elaborate your problem and what you have done so far to solve it. What have you researched so far? What code did you write and what's the problem with it?. Have a look at [ask] to get help.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the values who are alreday seen.

```js
var array = [40, 2, 40, 10, 5, 6, 10, 5, 6, 18, 15],
    seen = array.filter((s => v => s.has(v) || !s.add(v))(new Set));

console.log(seen);
```

Comment: You filtered the array, Wat is the value of s and v in your code

Comment: `s` is the instance of `Set` as closure and `v` is a value from the array.

Comment: @NinaScholz how the `v` is available inside IIFE it this because of closure.